# How to merge or push or add new key and values to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

The array is like this

```
Array 1
(
    [2014-07-01] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-01
            [totalr] => 13
        )

    [2014-07-02] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-02
            [totalr] => 18
        )
   //... one for each day of the month
)
```

An then I have another array very similar to the one before the only key that changes is the key "total"

```
Array 2
(
    [2014-07-01] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-01
            [members] => 21
        )

    [2014-07-02] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-02
            [members] => 30
        )
   //... one for each day of the month
)
```

So with both arrays I need to build a single array, so the final array need to be like this:

```
Final Array
(
    [2014-07-01] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-01
            [totalr] => 13
            [members] => 21
        )

    [2014-07-02] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-02
            [totalr] => 18
            [members] => 30
        )
// One for each day of the month
)
```

the key for each block is the same for each array... I already try array_merge didn't work... so how do I do that?...

**UPDATE - 8-13-2014 08:12**

Based on @ChicagoRedSox comment I find this function:

```
    function juntaArrs($arr1, $arr2) {
        if (!is_array($arr1) or !is_array($arr2)) { return $arr2; }
        foreach ($arr2 AS $sKey2 => $sValue2) {
            $arr1[$sKey2] = juntaArrs(@$arr1[$sKey2], $sValue2);
        }
        return $arr1;
    }
  $new_arr = juntaArrs($a1, $a2);
  print_r($new_arr);
```

it works perfectly!! thank you.

Comment: `array_merge_recursive`?

Comment: More complex than that, since recursive will convert a duplicate key to an array rather than overwriting the value. Check out this function (`array_merge_recursive_distinct`) from the PHP page on the `array_merge_recursive` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195

Comment: Worked with a function... see my update... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// start with a new array
$newArr = array();
// for every key and value in array 1
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    // add in the new array at key each key an array with date (the key),
    // totalr (the second value in the sub-array) and numbers (the second value in
    // the array 2 at the key position
    $newArr[$k] = array('date'=>$k, 'totalr'=>$v[1], 'numbers'=>$arr2[$k][1]);
}
// it's what we obtain
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: You should offer some explanation of your answer.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it only add's whatever value is in $k and $v[1] goes empty as well for the value the second array arr2[$k][0] is shows empty... may be is I add another foreach inside the first foreach width the second array... I'll see what happen...